# Change the fragment to another fragment within a setOnclick

Tags: java, android

I have a simple block code and i wish pass this fragment to another fragment with a click in a button.
If anyone could help me I would appreciate it

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(final LayoutInflater inflater, final ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_inicio,container,false);

    linearLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.clientea);

    linearLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Teste",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });

    return view;
}
```

Comment: You can't pass a fragment as an argument to another fragment. Arguments you can pass are basic types like, boolean, Int, String, serialized objects or parcelized objects. Why do you want to pass a fragment to another fragment?

Comment: Dominik I want to change the fragment, i want to move from one fragment to another.

Comment: You can get a hold of the fragmentmanager 
https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/fragmentmanager
And navigate to the new fragment in your onClick function.
get a reference to the fragmentmanager in your onCreateView and use the reference in your onClick to navigate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will show a simple way with code.
There are one Activity and two Fragments in the code.

First , the MainActivity contains the FragmentOne.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.container, new FragmentOne(), "")
            .addToBackStack(null)
            .commit();

}}
```

Then FragmentOne, there is a button in it, which will jump FragmentTwo when click.

```
public class FragmentOne extends Fragment {

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one, container, false);
    Button btnClick = view.findViewById(R.id.btn);
    btnClick.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.container, new FragmentTwo())
                    .addToBackStack(null)
                    .commit();
        }
    });
    return view;
}}
```

The last is the FragmentTwo:

```
public class FragmentTwo extends Fragment {

  @Override
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_two, container, false);      
    return view;
  }
}
```

I could give the xml if you want.

Comment: This answer will work and is concise but it creates a dependency between the fragments. For clean code, and loose coupling, this approach should be avoided. In the answer I have provided the fragments know nothing about each other and the MainActivity acts as a controller.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer, I already implemented the code and it works.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience with Android development, the approach that is taken to this problem is to create a functional interface, implement the interface in the Activity that the fragments are managed by and then do the fragment swapping inside the method provided by the interface.

So first create an interface, let's call it `IFragmentToSwap`.

```
public interface IFragmentToSwap{
    void OnButtonClicked();
}
```

Then in the Activity that controls fragment transactions you need to implement this interface.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements IFragmentToSwap {

   @Override
    public void OnButtonClicked()
    {
        //Swap fragment here
    }
}
```

Now in your fragment in the `OnAttach` override method you should do the following:

```
private IFragmentToSwap mListener;

@Override
public void onAttach(Context context)
{
    super.onAttach(context);

    if (context instanceof IFragmentToSwap)
    {
        mListener = (MainActivity) context;
    }
    else
    {
        throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                + " must implement IFragmentToSwap");
    }
}
```

And in the method you provided that is contained inside your fragment you would call the method on the functional interface when a click happens, like this:

```
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(final LayoutInflater inflater, final 
            ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_inicio,container,false);

        linearLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.clientea);

        linearLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                mListener.OnButtonClicked();

                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Teste",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        return view;
    }
```

And don't forget to detach the listener in the `OnDetach` override:

```
public void onDetach()
{
    super.onDetach();

    mListener = null;
}
```

This is the most common approach I have seen to swapping fragments on Android.